# GYP Error installing Node on pcduino

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, linaro

I'm installing NodeJS on a pcDuino v2 (running Linaro 12.07), and during the `./configure` step i get the following error:

`gyp:name 'arm_version' is not defined while evaluating condition 'arm_version==7' in /home/ubuntu/node/deps/v8/tools/gyp/v8.gyp while loading dependencies of /home/ubuntu/node/node.gyp while trying to load /home/ubuntu/node/node.gyp
Error running GYP`

I've installed all the dependencies that it told me to install in the tutorials I've found so what am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

Add the following to 'variables' in common.gypi:

`'arm_version%' : '1',` so it looks like this:

```
{
  'variables': {
  'werror': '',                    # Turn off -Werror in V8 build.
  'visibility%': 'hidden',         # V8's visibility setting
  'target_arch%': 'ia32',          # set v8's target architecture
  'host_arch%': 'ia32',            # set v8's host architecture
  'want_separate_host_toolset': 0, # V8 should not build target and host
  'library%': 'static_library',    # allow override to 'shared_library' for D$
  'component%': 'static_library',  # NB. these names match with what V8 expec$
  'msvs_multi_core_compile': '0',  # we do enable multicore compiles, but not$
  'gcc_version%': 'unknown',
  'clang%': 0,
  'python%': 'python',
  'arm_version%' : '1',

# Enable V8's post-mortem debugging only on unix flavors.
```

Comment: I had a similar problem with a ARMv7 processor and resolved it by adding `'arm_version%': 7` to v8.gyp